# jQuery check which select has fired

Tags: jquery

i have a jQuery function that fires on any of two selects tags change , but my question is what the wrong i did in the conditions that check which select tag has fired

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aqQuestionIoli .ConceptSelector1,#aqAnswerIoli .ConceptSelector1').on('change',function(){
        var concetp = $(this).val();
        alert(concetp);
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept/"+concetp+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '<option>Select IO</option>';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options+="<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            if ($('#aqQuestionIoli .ConceptSelector1').length){
                $("#aqIoQuesSelector").html(options);
            }
            if ($('#aqAnswerIoli .ConceptSelector1').length){
                $("#aqIoAnswerSelector").html(options);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[code html here](http://jsfiddle.net/QDvwK/)

Comment: why down vote ? isn't a problem?

Comment: i said , that i can't check what select has changed

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do it. One would be to save a reference to "this" before you do your $.getJSON call and then compare on return. Another would be to add/remove a "selected" class.

Comment: @bygrace would u put an example please

Comment: k, see my answer below. I can't run it without your HTML so I hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aqQuestionIoli .ConceptSelector1,#aqAnswerIoli .ConceptSelector1').on('change',function(){
        var concetp = $(this).val();
        alert(concetp);
        var context = this;
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept/"+concetp+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '<option>Select IO</option>';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options+="<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            if (context === $('#aqQuestionIoli .ConceptSelector1')[0]){
                $("#aqIoQuesSelector").html(options);
            }
            if (context === $('#aqAnswerIoli .ConceptSelector1')[0]){
                $("#aqIoAnswerSelector").html(options);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Look at this for a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/6zsnx/1/
Again, there are a number of ways you could do this. If we could see your HTML we could probably give you a cleaner answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this part:

```
            if ($('#aqQuestionIoli .ConceptSelector1').length){
                $("#aqIoQuesSelector").html(options);
            }
            if ($('#aqAnswerIoli .ConceptSelector1').length){
                $("#aqIoAnswerSelector").html(options);
            }
```

They didn't check which select tag has fired. It's just check the document has that elemet.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aqQuestionIoli .ConceptSelector1,#aqAnswerIoli .ConceptSelector1').on('change',function(){
        var concetp = $(this).val();
        alert(concetp);
        var thisid = this.id;
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept/"+concetp+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '<option>Select IO</option>';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options+="<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            if (thisid == 'aqQuestionIoli')){
                $("#aqIoQuesSelector").html(options);
            }
            if (thisid == 'aqAnswerIoli'){
                $("#aqIoAnswerSelector").html(options);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you for this information , and so how can i check which select have changed ?

Comment: you can't use thisid inside getJSON , because it will be undifein , cos another function , and NetBeans editor tells me that the first thisid is not used ,

Comment: i mean still the same error and the two select tags are fired

Comment: i also tried `var thisid = $(this).id;` but also doesn't work :(

Comment: There's a mistake @bitoshi. You are not comparing but assigning ;). I guess thats a typo.

Comment: @Jashwant i also tried == , but doesn't work  , but after using == my editor knows that id,

Comment: If his selector is '#aqQuestionIoli .ConceptSelector1' rather than '#aqQuestionIoli.ConceptSelector1' then the ID is not 'aqQuestionIoli'. That would be an ancestor ID.

Comment: @FernadoMargin `getJSON` is called in the main function. Previously I assign `var thisid = this.id;`.

Comment: If you want to take that approach then depending on his HTML you could use the "closest" function to find the ancestor with that ID (http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: @bitoshi.n really thank you for helping , i got an answer , thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `id` to assign the options, that way you don't even need to check which has changed:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('#' + id).html(options);
```

I haven't tested it but I don't see why that wouldn't work (unless I've missed something :|)

Comment: but in your case you asign the options to the select no to my element , anyway thanks for helping i got an answer , but i love your way in coding and i will use it , thank you

Comment: Why even selects an `id` if you have `$(this)` :) Its like double overhead :). You can always use `$(this).html(options);. Also, in `$.getJSON` context `$(this)` doesnt refer to `selects`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aqQuestionIoli .ConceptSelector1,#aqAnswerIoli .ConceptSelector1').on('change',function(){
        var concetp = $(this).val();
        var select = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(select);
        var $this = $(this);
        // the value of select can tell which select was fired.
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept/"+concetp+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '<option>Select IO</option>';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options+="<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            $this.html(options);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i don't want to set the `options` to the fired selects , any way thank you and i got an answer :), really thank you